# PHP Can't get data back from a curl call

Tags: php

I'm sure this has been answered, but I just can't figure out the right question to ask the search, so here goes:

I have a calling program that's doing a curl call to another program - however I'm not getting anything back from the called program.

Here's the calling program (Please excuse the rookie coding - I'm learning as I go with this project)....

```
<?php
session_start();

$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$part = "12345";

$strConnect = "AppServer://1.2.3.4/appsrv";
$strUser = "cono91|oper=1234";

$_SESSION["part"] = $part;
$_SESSION["strConnect"] = $strConnect;
$_SESSION["strUser"] = $strUser;
$_SESSION["response"] = "init";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://5.6.7.8/test/Pricing.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$data = array('part' => $part,'strConnect' => $strConnect,'strUser' => 
$strUser);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($r);

var_dump($_SESSION); /* Just returns the $_SESSION var's I set above */

?>
```

And what it's calling:

```
<?php
session_start();

$part = $_SESSION['part'];
$strConnect = $_SESSION['strConnect'];
$strUser = $_SESSION['strUser'];


//$part = "341241";
//$strConnect = "AppServer://1.2.3.4/appsrv";
//$strUser = "cono=9|oper=xxx";

$soapUrl = "http://5.6.7.8/api/ApiService.asmx?op=Pricing";

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<Pricing xmlns="X.WS">
<connectString>' .$strConnect. '</connectString>
<userCode>' .$strUser. '</userCode>
<requestObject>
<customerNumber>55555</customerNumber>
<warehouse>WHSE</warehouse>
<quantity>1</quantity>
<productCode>' .$part. '</productCode>
</requestObject>
</Pricing>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
"POST /api/ApiService.asmx HTTP/1.1",
"Host: 5.6.7.8",
"Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
"Content-Length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
"SOAPAction: X.WS/Pricing"
); 

$url = $soapUrl;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$pos = strpos($response,"<OEPricingResult>");
$rx = substr($response,$pos,strlen($response));

$response1 = str_replace("</soap:Body>","",$rx);
$response2 = str_replace("</soap:Envelope>","",$response1);
$response3 = str_replace("</OEPricingResponse>","",$response2);

$response3 = "<xml>" .$response3. "</xml>";

$_SESSION["response"] = $response3;

var_dump($_SESSION);

print_r($response3); /* Gives me the output from the curl call this program makes


?>
```

So when program #1 does it's surl call to program #2 - it just returns nothing.  So I forced in the variables in program #2 ran it stand alone and get the output I expected (in a command line and web call).  I've tried to return the data in every way I can figure out - but after a few days of this, I just don't know the next question to ask.

So - how do I get the data from program #2 back to program #1?

I appreciate any help I can get on this....

Comment: Can you explain a little but more, not sure what exactly you are doing in the first file

Comment: the Sessions on two different servers are two different sessions, so setting a 'response' in there won't have any effect. You need to _echo_ what you wanna return. `echo $response3`;

Comment: when you `var_dump($r)` (in first file) you get _nothing_ at all?

Comment: As @Jeff mentions, the result is in `$r`, set due to `$r = curl_exec($ch);`. You need to assign this result to a session variable before you can use it via session.

Comment: @ Innervisions: Program #1 get's data from an external source and feeds that to program #2 for talking to a 3rd server

Comment: @Jeff: Actually, program #1 and Program #2 both reside on the same server in the same directory

Comment: @Jeff (pt2) - You, nothing at all.  The odd thing is that if I set the variables in program #2 (you'll see I have them commented out in my example), program #2 runs fine - I just get nothing back when it's called form program #1

Comment: why do you do a curl call then? Simply include it... (and return the value)

Comment: _"I just get nothing back"_ - where? in $r?

Comment: @ Jaswinder Singh:  Isn't $r where I should be getting my response from Program #2?  Also, why is it that the $_SESSION['response'] variable never seems to change?  I load it with 'init' in program #1, but load program #2's response into it, but it still returns "init".

Comment: @Jeff:  Yep, program #1 does what appears to be a clean call, it's just that program #2 doesn't return anything.

Comment: _"but load program #2's response into it"_ - no, you don't. At least not in the code shown. And you never check what's in $r (in the code shown)

Comment: @Jeff: $r is checked in program #1 with $xml = simplexml_load_string($r);  (isn't it?)

Comment: no, it's not really. I guess `simplexml_load_string` will return false or null if it can't parse xml. since you don't return any xml from program#2 (only a print_r or a var_dump) it will fail - and show nothing. So please re-read my first two comments.

Answer (score 0):

A script invoked through `curl` doesn't inherit the session variables from the calling script. You're sending those parameters in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, and you need to read them from `$_POST`, not `$_SESSION`.

So in the second script, you should use:

```
$part = $_POST['part'];
$strConnect = $_POST['strConnect'];
$strUser = $_POST['strUser'];
```

Comment: Thanks - I tried $_POST, but still get no response :(

Comment: In your first script you have `$part = "12345";`. In the second script, the commented-out hard-coded value is `$part = "341241";`. Could that make a difference?

Comment: I hard coded all the var's in the socond program and tried it - the first program still got nothing back to display.

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning anything? What does `var_dump(strlen($r))` show? `$xml` will be empty because the second script is returning stuff other than XML. It does `var_dump($_SESSION)` and `print_r($response3)`, these print extra stuff before and after the XML.